# pull text between characters

Tags: powershell

How do I pull text between two words? I know regex can do this and I have been looking around but the code I try just does not work for me at all...as clueless as a brick with regex...so probably am doing it totally wrong...

I have a text file and want to query whatever is displayed between these text strings:

> [Problem Devices]
>
> Device    PNP Device ID   Error Code
>
> [USB]

I tried doing this but getting no where!

```
$devices = Get-Content c:\temp\dev.txt | out-string [regex]::match($devices,'(?<=\<Problem Devices\>).+(?=\<USB\>)',"singleline").value.trim()

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:141
+ $devices = Get-Content c:\temp\dev.txt | out-string [regex]::match($devices,'(?<=\<Problem Devices\>).+(?=\<USB\>)',"
singleline").value.trim <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (trim:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 1):

Piping to `out-string` is not needed; `get-content` is sending each line of the file into the pipeline as a separate object. So you want to iterate through those objects with a `foreach-object`.

```
$devices = Get-Content c:\temp\dev.txt | foreach-object{[regex]::match($devices,'(?<=\<Problem Devices\>).+(?=\<USB\>)',"singleline").value.trim()}
```

However, you are still left with the problem of attempting to `trim()` a `null` object - if your regex match doesn't find a match, you can't call `value.trim()`.

Your regex tries to match on `<Problem Devices>` when your input file has `[Problem Devices]`.

Rather than try to do everything in a single set of pipeline steps, break your problem down:

1. For each line in the file, check for [Problem Devices]
2. For each subsequent line, if it is [USB], exit the loop. If it is not [USB], capturing each line into a variable (build an array of these lines)
3. After the loop, iterate over each element of the array you just built to parse each value out (creating a collection of `PSObjects` (one per device), or a collection of hashes (one per device), depending on your needs).

Comment: thanks a lot for that. Your steps do sound good but think that is too difficult for someone like me...it will take me ages just to figure out where to start!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with regex, there are other ways:

$test = $false

$devices = get-content file.txt |

foreach {

```
if ($_.trim() -eq '[Problem Devices]'){$test = $true}

elseif ($_.trim() -eq '[USB]') {$test = $false}

elseif ($test){$_}

} | where {$_.trim()}
```